# Cannot use empty key for Dictionary - Vim

Tags: vim, syntastic

I have a small-ish vim set up, and it appears whenever I open the vimrc file in vim, I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>46_VimEnterHook[14]..<SNR>46_UpdateErrors[15]..<SNR>46_CacheErrors[29].
.281:
line    7:
E713: Cannot use empty key for Dictionary
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

## **Update**

## Running :scriptname, I see line 46 points to syntastic.

In terms of plugins, I have the following:
ctrlp, ensime-vim, nerdtree, supertab.vmb, syntastic, vim-scala

This is my vimrc:

```
  1 set nocompatible
  2 set number
  3 execute pathogen#infect()
  4 
  5 filetype plugin indent on
  6 syntax on
  7 
  8 "auto open nerdtree
  9 autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
 10 autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif
 11 map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
 12 autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif
 13 let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable = '+'
 14 let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible = '~'
 15 
 16 set tabstop=8 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=4 smarttab
 17 
 18 "syntastic
 19 set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
 20 set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
 21 set statusline+=%*
 22 
 23 let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
 24 let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
 25 let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
 26 let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
 27 
 28 "vim-ensime
 29 autocmd BufWritePost *.scala silent :EnTypeCheck
 30 nnoremap <localleader>t :EnTypeCheck<CR>
```

I have no clue where to start to resolve this annoying warning, and would appreciate any help. I'm running vim-nox-py2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The "46" entry returned by `:scriptname` (or `:echo filter(split(execute('scriptname'), "\n"), 'v:val =~ " 46:"')` with a more recent version of vim) will give you the culprit. For here, you can edit your question, or directly open an issue where the plugin is hosted.

Comment: Upgrade syntastic to the latest master HEAD.  If that doesn't fix the problem please open an issue at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues).